# Debugging problem on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to run a piece of code written in Matlab that contains the following:

```
function list = shellsort(list);
interval = floor(length(list)/3);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Not enough input arguments. 
Error in shellsort (line 3)
interval = floor(length(list)/3);
```

Any ideas on how to debug it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Is there a StackExchange forum specifically on Matlab?

Comment: Theoretically this is on topic if you edit as you use matlab on iPad or on Mac. Hard for me to guess which engineering or math site might have this on scope as well.

Comment: My mathlab is a bit rusty but what are you trying to do here? Define a function?

Comment: Not enough content to know why you get not enough input arguments, since there's no function call here that should have too few arguments.